# Filter in tshark returning everything when there should be nothing

Tags: batch-file, wireshark, tshark

I am using the tshark command:

```
tshark -r <file> -R "bootp" -T fields -e wlan.sa -e wlan.da -E separator="," >   <file.csv>
```

The pcap I am running it against has no DHCP and when I put that filter in wireshark  it shows nothing. However when the tshark command is run it returns all MAC addresses. This is in part of a batch script in Windows but the rest of the script runs perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you replace `<file>` and `<file.csv>` with valid files name (without `<>`) in the batch script ?

Comment: yes I was just substituting them for the example, I apologize if that was misleading.